# Motivation behind POVM and projective measurement

Tags: measurement, povm, projection-operator

This is in reference to Quantum Computation and Quantum Information by Michael A. Nielsen and Isaac L. Chung [page 90, 92].

Any POVM elements $E_{m}$ are defined as $E_{m} = M_{m}^{\dagger}M_{m}$. A set $S_{E_{m}}$ is a POVM if all its elements are $E_{m}$ and only $E_{m}$.

On page 90: The author started with an example of a measurement operator, projector $P_{m}$, as being an example of POVM element. Since $P_{m}$ is a measurement operator, it must satisfy 1) positive - valued operator 2) the completeness relation.
Each element in the set $S_{P_{m}}$ = $\\{P_{m}\\}$ are thus the POVM elements associated with the measurement. This follows from the fact that $P_{m}^{\dagger}P_{m} = E_{m} = P_{m}^{2} = P_{m}$ holds for all $m$. Indeed, the set of $P_{m}$ forms a POVM $S_{P_{m}}$.

On page 92: The author(s) started off with a POVM $E_{m}$ before proceeding to show there must exists measurement operators, beyond that of projective operators.

I'm struggling to understand the point that the author is trying to bring across. It seems like 1) the point is that measurement operators are not unique but this should be clear in the preceding sections (that we are not beholden to stick with projectors) or 2) given a POVM, one can always decompose it to its constituent measurement operator(s) with the guarantee that the measurement operator(s) will satisfy the property of it being a positive operator and the completeness relation.

Aside: what motivates the defining of $M_{m} = \sqrt(E_{m})$?
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Quickly answering the aside: the $M_m$ are Kraus operators that tell you how a state evolves. Kraus operator decompositions are not unique, just as (for example) the square root of an operator is not unique

Comment: @QuantumMechanic I have only very recently heard about Kraus operators. Are these operators applying a "more" generalised quantum operation to their unitary operator counterparts, both Kraus and unitary falling under quantum operations?

Comment: Exactly. The possible ways of a quantum state being transformed into a quantum state are not restricted to unitary operations; Kraus operators do the trick (and that's the most general evolution possible that is "completely positive and trace-preserving" (eg https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/711133/291677)